# my Polymer website does not work on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, polymer

The page is at http://5heurescod.tk. Please inspect the source to see what I could have done wrong.

It works well on Chrome but not on firefox.. Did I forget to import something?

(edit: when I say it doesn't work, I mean that the menu on the left is not clickable and the javascript function getCard(); which should be called at start is not called.)

I used

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer
bower install --save Polymer/core-elements
bower install --save Polymer/paper-elements
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It works for me but what do you mean by "does not work"? That's not a technical description.

Comment: The 5heurescod.tk page works in firefox here, but not the tutorial application: https://www.polymer-project.org/apps/polymer-tutorial/finished/

Firefox 33.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a glance, I'd say:

- make sure the web components polyfill (`webcomponents.js`, formerly `platform.js`) is loaded first, certainly before any HTML imports, since this includes the polyfill for HTML imports.
- wait for the `polymer-ready` event before manipulating any of the DOM or setting CoreStyle properties. You might be able to get away with this on Chrome, because native HTML imports work a little differently -- but definitely not on Firefox or any browser without native HTML imports.

  See: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready

Comment: Do you also happen to know why the tutorial application doesn't work in Firefox (33.1)? https://www.polymer-project.org/apps/polymer-tutorial/finished/ I tried adding javascript code for waiting for the polymer-ready event first, but it didn't work out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking at https://www.polymer-project.org/apps/polymer-tutorial/finished/ with Firefox 33.1 on OS X and it works correctly, except that on initial load the selected tab underline is showing up on both tabs. It may be that you saw an intermittent outage when we were updating our site. If you're still seeing this problem, what OS are you on and what are you seeing?

Comment: at the time of writing this answer platform was used but this is outdated now (see the answer below) so...this answer is wrong as it is stated. Consider revising or adding a new answer

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had all the imports in an elements.html (including the webcomponents.js). I moved the script tag from the elements.html to index.html and it worked. I put the script tag right before importing the elements.html. The resulting index.html was:

```
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">    
<title></title>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
</script>

<link rel="import" href="elements.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/core_toolbar.css">    
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

html imports are not supported by Firefox, visit https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html

And platform.js i no longer used, now you should include firstly webcomponents.js, visit https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/platform.html

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Firefox,
I recommend you to use the polyfill **webcomponents-lite.js** rather **webcomponents.js** which has some issue with smartdevices.
As it is said in **https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/browsers**

> We recommend using the webcomponents-lite.js version of the polyfills
>   with Polymer 1.0+. This version is designed to be used with Shady DOM,
>   and does not contain the full Shadow DOM polyfill.
>
> Although the full webcomponents.js polyfill works with Polymer 1.0+,
>   we do not recommend using it. This version contains the full Shadow
>   DOM polyfill, which is known to have high performance overhead.

You need also to pay attention for the tag **link** which does not work inside your webcomponent, in that case just move it to the page which hostes the webcomponent.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the fact that I was loading webcomponents-lite.min.js, instead of the full version, webcomponents.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

> **Its all about browser support for web components.**

Where browser's native support is not available for web components, then this pollyfills under `"bower_components/webcomponentsjs/"` Either of `"webcomponents.js"` or `"webcomponents-lite.js"` is needed.

See: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/browsers